# switch statement giving unexpected ',' error

Tags: r, switch-statement

I am trying to create a simple switch to determine start date based on quarter.

My code is below:

```
qtr_start <- function(qtr, yr){
  switch(qtr,
         1 = paste(yr, "0101", sep = ""),
         2 = paste(yr, "0104", sep = ""),
         3 = paste(yr, "0107", sep = ""),
         4 = paste(yr, "0110", sep = ""))
}
```

This gives the error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"switch(qtr,
         1 ="
>          2 = paste(yr, "0104", sep = ""),
Error: unexpected ',' in "         2 = paste(yr, "0104", sep = ""),"
>          3 = paste(yr, "0107", sep = ""),
Error: unexpected ',' in "         3 = paste(yr, "0107", sep = ""),"
>          4 = paste(yr, "0110", sep = ""))
Error: unexpected ')' in "         4 = paste(yr, "0110", sep = ""))"
```

I am really struggling to see how this is different from the help version:

```
centre <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
         mean = mean(x),
         median = median(x),
         trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
}
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: Fwiw, in a case like this, I would put the rules in a table, `data.frame(qrt = 1:4, suff = c(whatever))`, and merge on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use numbers as the names of cases. Just leave them away (R will use the first case for `1`, the second for `2` and so on, or use strings [edit] and use `as.character` on the number.

So either

```
 qtr_start <- function(qtr, yr){
     switch(qtr,
        paste(yr, "0101", sep = ""),
        paste(yr, "0104", sep = ""),
        paste(yr, "0107", sep = ""),
        paste(yr, "0110", sep = "")) }
```

or

```
qtr_start <- function(qtr, yr){
  switch(as.character(qtr),
         "1" = paste(yr, "0101", sep = ""),
         "2" = paste(yr, "0104", sep = ""),
         "3" = paste(yr, "0107", sep = ""),
         "4" = paste(yr, "0110", sep = ""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I decided to leave it in, but add an `as.character` - sometimes you have numbers that do not start with 1

Comment: Yea great idea, I didn't really like having them unlabled, that makes it much clearer - thank you

Answer (score 2):

We need to have backquotes for numbers to get the statement to run, but effectively these will be ignored (thus they are only indicative).

The `switch` statement will evaluate to the order in which the statements are placed, ie in the example below, passing `qtr = 2` to the function will always return `paste0(yr, "0104")`, regardless of the number in backquotes.

```
qtr_start <- function(qtr, yr){
 switch(qtr,
     `1` = paste0(yr, "0101"),
     `2` = paste0(yr, "0104"),
     `3` = paste0(yr, "0107"),
     `4` = paste0(yr, "0110"))
 }

qtr_start(1, 2014)
#[1] "20140101"
```

Comment: Actually the names are ignored when using a numeric value as the first parameter. If you switch the order of parameters, you will only match on position, not name. Better not to name the parameters at all. For example: `switch(3,\`3\` = "a",\`1\` = "b",\`2\` = "c",\`4\` = "d")` returns "c" not "a"

Comment: @akrun, I edited this to highlight MrFlick's point, I hope you don't mind